# Better Term than "Decisecond"

Tags: coding-style, naming-conventions

I have a data element with units of tenths of a second (that is, the value "123" really means "12.3 seconds").

What is a good term for an descriptive identifier for this type of data?  I'd be comfortable writing something like `durationMilliseconds` or `durationMicroseconds`, but `durationDeciseconds` looks odd. `durationInTenthsOfSeconds` doesn't make me happy either.

Comment: Decisecond is the correct term so just use it. No sense in defining a new term when one exists already. Also, off topic. You should be asking a thesaurus instead of Stack Overflow.

Comment: Decisecond is the correct term. It's just not used that often, that'w why it seems odd...

Comment: I don't come here asking for help in naming every variable; this just seemed like something that might have standard programmerese that I haven't run across.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Decisecond is the standard SI unit for this measurement, so I'd say using that is better than inventing something that may be ambiguous.

Actually, in the past I've used things like `TICKS_PER_100MS` for the same reason. But `durationIn100msPeriods` is just as bad as `durationInTenthsOfSeconds`.

Answer (score 3):

http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/decisecond

Comment: right, pasted wrong url, decasecond is 10 seconds, not a tenth

Answer (score 2):

Would `durationTenthsOfASecond` be too verbose?